# Laravel filters not working

Tags: php, laravel-4

Firstly I am sure these filters were originally working and I have no just noticed they are not.

My filters from filters.php

```
Route::filter('partnership', function()
{
    if (!Auth::check())
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
    elseif(Auth::check())
    {
        $access = Auth::user()->access;
        if(!$access == 'partnership')
        {
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }
    }
});

Route::filter('company', function()
{
    if (!Auth::check())
    {
        return Redirect::to('login');
    }
    elseif(Auth::check())
    {
        $access = Auth::user()->access;
        if(!$access == 'company')
        {
            return Redirect::to('login');
        }
    }
});
```

These are used to see if the user has the correct access level

My route groups look like this from routes.php

EDIT: Missed this part of the first filter group

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'partnership'), function ()
{
//Dashboard access
    Route::get('partnership_dashboard', array('as' => 'partnership_dashboard', function()
    {
        $count = DB::table('devices')->count();
        if ($count > 25)
        {
            $overLicense = $count - 25;
            $licenseWarning = 'The client is over their license quota by '.$overLicense;
            return View::make('partnership.partnership-dashboard')
                ->withErrors($licenseWarning);
        }
        else
        {
            return View::make('partnership.partnership-dashboard');
        }
    }));

    // Route for register form action
    Route::post('register', array('uses' => 'UsersController@partnership_create'));
```

My company group

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'company'), function ()
{
    //Dashboard access
    Route::get('dashboard', array('as' => 'dashboard', function()
    {
        // Get user data for dashboard drop down menu
        $users = DB::table('users')
            ->where('access', 'company')->get();
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($users as $user) {
            $full_name = $user->first_name." ".$user->last_name;
            $user_arr[$i] = array('name' => $full_name, 'user_id' => $user->id);
            $i++;
        }
        // Get device data for dashboard dropdown menu
        $devices = DB::table('devices')->get();
        $count = DB::table('devices')->count();
        if ($count > 25)
        {
            $overLicense = $count - 25;
            $licenseWarning = 'You are over your license quota by '.$overLicense; 
            return View::make('dashboard')
                ->with('users', $user_arr)
                ->with('devices', $devices)
                ->withErrors($licenseWarning);
        }
        else {
        return View::make('company.dashboard')
            ->with('users', $user_arr)
            ->with('devices', $devices);
        }
    }));
});
```

I have checked I am getting the correct data from the database. I'm just a bit stumped

Thanks in advance

Comment: which filter isn't working? both of them?  I don't see you using the `partnership` filter anywhere, only the `company` filter is being used.

Comment: I missed the first line out of the filter when I copy and pasted the code over posted the question. Yes both of them are not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!$access == 'partnership')
```

I think what you mean to say in this line (similar in the company filter) something like this:

```
if($access != 'partnership')
```

Looking at it the first way, you could have an access level equal to partnership, and this statement would return true:

```
$access == 'partnership'
```

Throwing the `!` in front negates the truth value, so it winds up false and you wind up with a logic error.

Comment: Thank you, I just couldn't see that for so long! Much apprciated

Comment: glad to help. sometimes its always easier with a second pair of eyes.